# AJAX Post form Variables to PHP Page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form that executes an AJAX function to submit form values to a PHP page. The PHP page just responds by echoing out the variables in a DIV.

It works with GET method, but I can't get it working with POST.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!-- 
    //Browser Support Code
    function ajaxFunction(){
        var ajaxRequest;

        try{
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e){
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try{
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e){
                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Browser Not Supported");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        // Get Response
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
        }
        var name=document.getElementById("name").value
        var email=document.getElementById("email").value
        ajaxRequest.open("POST", "process.php?name="+name+"&email="+email, true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null); 
    }
    //-->
    </script>
    <form name='Form1'>
      Name:  <input type='text'  name='name' id="name"/> <br />
      Email: <input type='text'  name='email' id="email"/> <br />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="ajaxFunction();">
    </form>
    <div id="response">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And the php page, process.php

```
    <?php
    echo date("H:i:s"); 
    echo "<br/>";
    // echo "Post Variables: ".$_POST['name']." ".$POST['email']; old code
            echo "Post Variables: ".$_POST['name']." ".$_POST['email'];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Get Variables: ".$_GET['name']." ".$_GET['email'];
    ?>
```

The response I get is:

11:32:05
Post Variables: 
Get Variables: name entered email entered

So i'm pretty sure it's to do with the variable being passed from PHP to Javascript.

Many thanks.

Comment: @MazIqbal The form method is irrelevant if you're using AJAX.

Comment: By default the method with which the information is passed to the php script is Get. You must specify in your ajax to pass the information via POST.

Comment: Yeah added method"post" no difference. The get is only working as I've appended the values to the URL, so the PHP page can request GET or POST ???

Comment: For one thing, this `$POST['email'];` should read as `$_POST['email'];` you forgot the underscore. @Paul

Comment: A little thing: in your process.php on line 4 you've written `$POST['email']` - the underscore is missing. But that should not be the point... can you try to do a `print_r($_REQUEST);`?

Comment: Already pointed out above @Robert --- Plus, that little point will put a damper on the OP's code.

Comment: $POST['email']; Corrected.

Comment: Which I posted above, a while ago ;-) @Paul

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> ajaxRequest.open("POST", "process.php?name="+name+"&email="+email, true);
> ajaxRequest.send(null);
> ```

That's not posting the variables. Here you're sending them as GET parameters, with an empty body for your POST request. Instead, use

```
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "process.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send("name="+name+"&email="+email);
```

or even better

```
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "process.php", true);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajaxRequest.send("name="+encodeURIComponent(name)+"&email="+encodeURIComponent(email));
```

Comment: Modified: ajaxRequest.send("name="+name+"&email="+email); no difference, even tried: ajaxRequest.send(name) just to be sure but no value passed.

Comment: Thanks, just saw the update. This works a bit :) ajaxRequest.send("name="+encodeURIComponent(name)+"&email="+encodeURIComponent(email)); I only get the name not the email, I'm guessing it's to do with the concatenation of the variables would you have the &email in a POST???? My mistake just spotted the error: $POST['email'] should be $_POST['email']. All working. :)

Comment: @Paul: Yes, if you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` :-) Seems like a PHP typo, use `$_POST` instead of `$POST` for the email